# How to export a PyQt5 QGraphicsScene which contains several QPixmapItems as an image?

Tags: python, export, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qpixmap

I am working in a PyQt5 project in which at the end of the process, the user has rearranged a set of images (`MovablePixmapItem(QtGui.QPixmap`)) in a canvas (`QGraphicsScene`) to their proper positions. Once at that point, the main idea is that the resulting `QGraphicsScene` should be exported as a whole image. I have searched the web looking for a way to solve this without much success.

Please any help with regards to this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use [QGraphicsScene.render()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#render).

Comment: Hi ekhumoro,
Thanks for your suggestion. I would like to know wish way do you think would be the most convenient between:
 the one you recommended;
or this one I have already used:

    def exportScene(self):
        pix = QtWidgets.QWidget.grab(self.graphicsView)
        pix.save("./capture.png", "PNG")

Comment: Well, you're in the best position to decide on that. Just try them both, and compare the results.